# Specifying a new location for ConfigurationProperties (Spring 2.7.13)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

Suppose I have both an `application.yml` and `query.yml` in my resources folder. If I have a class

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties()
public class QueryConfiguration
    private String propertyOne;
    private List<Integer> propertyTwo;
```

How can I specify QueryConfiguration to look in `query.yml` for these properties?